# Get an object by coordinates without using a name in Squish

Tags: python, squish

I have a problem, waitForObject or findObject only works with elements that are in names. But I need to get these objects simply by coordinates, I use x, y.
Is this in principle possible in Squish?

Comment: The record feature for test cases is able to do it, means if you start record and tap on the touchscreen or mouse on object then squish finds the clicked object. I don't know if you can access this feature via code, but I recommend to ask to squish support team.

Answer (score 0):

None of the currently available Squish editions offers functionality for this. However, it may be possible to use the native API of the GUI controls, for example (Squish for Qt with a Qt AUT (Application Under Test) [QWidget.childAt(x, y)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#childAt)).

One could also traverse the GUI object tree ([object.topLevelObjects()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#object.topLevelObjects-function), [object.children()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#object.children-function)) and query the (global) bounds of each individual object ([object.globalBounds()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#object.globalBounds-function)), but with that it is difficult to determine which of these are actually visible, hidden, overlaid by other objects, etc.

Comment: yes, both that and that method can be working, but I need to transfer coordinates to squish during work and receive the object that is there. and preferably without a previously known database or something like this